# Lower baselineskip in leadsheets

Tags: parskip, leadsheets

How can I lower the space between lines in the `leadsheets` package to make the songs more compact?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{leadsheets}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\ttdefault}

% these values are too extreme, I know.
% they just serve to make the point more clearly visible
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\linespread{0.4}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2pt}

\begin{document}
    This text here works.

    It is spaced in a readable but space conserving manner.    

    \begin{song}{
        title={Example Song}
    }
        \begin{verse}
            In this verse, the lines have a big distance.

            They are separated with a blank line in the source code.
        \end{verse}
        \begin{chorus}
            These ^{Ab}lines have ^{C}chords, which should of ^{Ebmaj7}course use more ^{G}space than in the verse

            But they could ^{F}still be formatted with a ^{C}lower distance to each other
        \end{chorus}
    \end{song}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us a short, **compilable** code resulting in your issue ...

Comment: All verses per default are lists in `leadsheets`. If you test an `itemize` (for example) in your setup you will observe similar effects.

Comment: Then I guess my question is: How can I lower the distance between list entries?